# Rails 4 + Sass - No background image in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, sass, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, puma

I know there are alot of similar questions/answers on SO about this, and I have tried at least 7 of the proposed methods. I can display my app's background image locally in a variety of ways. After trying for nearly 40 hours, there seems to be no way to render it in production. It runs on the following:

- Ruby 2.1.5
- Rails 4.1.8
- Puma 2.1 via Amazon Elastic Beanstalk (single instance - no load balancer)

I've tried every combination of **config.serve_static_assets=[true|false]** and setting **RAILS_SKIP_ASSET_COMPILATION** to true and false.

Ran **rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production**

Tried every path I can think of, but it's not finding the background image. One thing I noticed was that precompilation changes the name of the image when it copies to the public/assets directory. (*example: "foo.jpg" becomes "foo-ilfajwe8hjsa8erfjsdf.jpg"*) So I tried copying the original image files to the new public/assets directory, hoping the app would find them there. That didn't work.

I'm thinking it might be how I'm referencing it in my css, because oddly the favicon file displays as does the fonts from my app's "fonts" folder. And both have their names appended to just like the background image.

Here is my application.html.erb..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Capstone v1.4.5</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= favicon_link_tag 'capstone_icon.png' %>
</head>
<body>
    <% if notice %>
      <p class="alert alert-success"><%= notice %></p>
    <% end %>
    <% if alert %>
      <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= alert %></p>
    <% end %>
    <%= render 'navigation' %>
    <main>
        <%= yield %>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the application.css.sass..

```
/*
 *= require bootstrap.min
 */

@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"

@font-face 
    font-family: 'Cinzel-Regular'
    src: font-url('Cinzel-Regular.ttf')

@font-face 
    font-family: 'Oxygen'
    src: font-url('Oxygen.otf')

html
    position: relative
    min-height: 100%

body 
    background-image: image-url("snowy_prairie_bg.jpg")
    background-repeat: no-repeat
    background-position: center top
    font-family: 'Oxygen'
    margin: 0 0 95px
```

The contents of my *public* directory (after precompilation)

```
application-6cca23f2f72df0ad7d26279535719396.css
application-6cca23f2f72df0ad7d26279535719396.css.gz
application-fddd9c84ba451526dbd2ef5bf46e494c.js
application-fddd9c84ba451526dbd2ef5bf46e494c.js.gz
bootstrap
capstone_icon-ed6ffe0ae4bbbb56a8b74a4d7ff230cf.png
capstone_icon.png
Cinzel-Regular-59dcda430d3afc3ace221f1835d7fb08.ttf
images
manifest-73d04c0fd1290b15fb280becfcf62b7b.json
Oxygen-1c736bd9242de63cf87c07f0a48c9b5c.otf
Oxygen-Bold-01bc72645c864aa090d57754565ef634.otf
Oxygen-BoldItalic-cfe32a5aedef7b25f8b1efdfcbdbd72a.otf
Oxygen-Italic-2a51c29c8f2bd242ac27e6fb7860f6a1.otf
snowy_prairie_bg-d246fbbe1178a09d38df31be96aee79a.jpg
snowy_prairie_bg.jpg
```

Am I referencing the image wrong in my css? Again, it renders great locally. Should I be using Passenger instead of Puma? This is not a very small app and I've got alot invested in the database, also hosted on Amazon. But like I said, **I'm approaching 40 hours just trying to get this background rendered**.

If you have any ideas, please help. I am willing to try anything!

Thank you

FYI - the above bootstraps, fonts, other images and sass styles render perfectly. It's just the background image. Thanks

**EDIT**: When I go to the page, [capstonesavings.com](http://www.capstonesavings.com), the following error is shown in the dev. console: *Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)*. Do I need to change permissions on something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, SO I THINK I FIXED IT!

Most of the above code is correct, but I changed the following from the above application.css.sass..

*Changed*

```
background-image: image-url("snowy_prairie_bg.jpg")
```

*To*

```
background-image: asset-url("snowy_prairie_bg.jpg")
```

Then, I SSH'ed into the instance (**eb ssh**) and did the following:

> **cd /var/app/current**

*followed by*

> **sudo chmod 755 public/assets/snowy_prairie_bg-d246fbbe1178a09d38df31be96aee79a.jpg**

I had tried the above change to the SaSS before, but it didn't work without changing permissions. Thanks to Chrome developer tools, I noticed a (tiny) error flag when the page was rendered. I clicked it and it showed the 403 error that I added in the above edit. This is some stuff that Amazon uses to make things secure, since I guess you can route your log files, etc. to the associated S3 bucket. So that's why I explicitly targeted the image in question when changing the perms. This site isn't going to have a ton of images, but if it did I'd probably take the time to elaborate on the storage within the bucket and set broader perms accordingly.

This saved the day for me. Hope it helps someone else.